# Binding datatemplate to ContentControl's Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

How to bind textbox text property, within datatemplate,  to ContentControl Content property?
(Without bindng via ElementName)

This is my code( that doesn't work):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Temp">
       <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Height="20" Width="Auto"/>           
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl  ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource Temp}" Content="1"/>           
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a relative source binding:

```xml
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Content}"
```

**Edit:** I probably should note that, in terms of what the binding targets, this is equivalent to `{Binding}`, as the `DataContext` in the `ContentTemplate` is the `Content`.

However binding directly to the `DataContext` will not propagate back to the source `DataContext`, hence the `Content` of the `ContentControl` would *not* change when when using this binding (or the two-way compliant variation `{Binding .}`, which changes absolutely nothing as far as I can tell).